# Python: Copy File Using Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, cp

Please correct me if I am wrong here.
A goal: to copy a file by spawning into another process (so actual copying is not "locking" the process that calls it).

```
cmd = ['cp', '/Users/username/Pictures/2Gb_ImageFile.tif', '/Volume/HugeNetworkDrive/VerySlow/Network/Connection/Destination.tif']

def copyWithSubprocess(cmd):        
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

copyWithSubprocess(cmd)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "locking" the process? This will still wait for the child process to terminate. (Edit: the question has been edited; this comment made more sense when the "communicate" call was still included)

Comment: whats the question ? ... subprocess should not block until you call `comunnicate` or some other method that must wait ...

Comment: @JeremyRoman why would that wait for the subprocess to finish? (Im almost positive it does not and continues executing immediatly after spawning)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Question was edited between when I commented and when you saw it. :)

Comment: ahhh gotcha ... I was really confused for a minute :P

Comment: You didn't state a problem. Is there a bug? An exception? Give us some more specifics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` won't "lock" your parent process.

`cmd` may stall  itself if it generates enough output due to the full pipe buffers. If you want to discard subprocess' output then use `DEVNULL` instead of `PIPE`:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb') #NOTE: it is already defined in Python 3.3+
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
# ...
```

if you want to process the output without blocking the main thread then you could use several approaches: `fcntl`, `select`, named pipes with iocp, [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279). The latter is a more portable way:

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
bind(p.stdout, stdout_callback)
bind(p.stderr, stderr_callback)
# ...
```

where `bind()` function:

```
from contextlib import closing
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread

def bind(pipe, callback, chunksize=8192):
    def consume():
        with closing(pipe):
            for chunk in iter(partial(pipe.read, chunksize), b''):
                callback(chunk)
    t = Thread(target=consume)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return t
```

You don't need an external process to copy a file in Python without blocking the main thread:

```
import shutil
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=shutil.copy, args=['source-file', 'destination']).start()
```

Python can release GIL during I/O so the copying happens both concurrently and in parallel with the main thread.

You could compare it with a script that uses multiple processes:

```
import shutil
from multiprocessing import Process

Process(target=shutil.copy, args=['source-file', 'destination']).start()
```

If you want to cancel the copying when your program dies then set `thread_or_process.daemon` attribute to `True`.

Comment: There are 'stdout_callback' and 'stderr_callback' variables being sent as the arguments to bind() function....    bind(p.stdout, stdout_callback) and bind(p.stderr, stderr_callback). If possible would you please clarify where those variable we've got from? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sputnix: It is your functions that process subprocess' stdout/stderr. Do you see `callback(chunk)` in the code? For example: `def stdout_callback(chunk): print("Got %d bytes on stdout" % len(chunk))`

Comment: Please take a look at the code I posted at the bottom of this page... It is a code I try to run. It gives me an error:   "NameError: global name 'stdout_callback' is not defined"

Comment: @Sputnix: It is **your** function. You must define it "if you want to process the output". See the previous comment on how you could do it. If you don't know what do you want to do with the subprocess' output then use the variant with `DEVNULL`.

Comment: I've got it now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle complicated asynchronous processes in Python is to use the `multiprocessing` library, which was designed specifically to support such tasks and has an interface that closely parallels that of the `threading` module (indeed I have written code that can switch between multi-threading and multi-processing operations mostly by importing one library or the other, but this required fairly rigorous limits on which parts of the modules were utilized).

[Edit: removed spurious advice about threading and made my opening assertion less bombastic]

Comment: It would be interesting to see how multiprocessing could be used with subprocess when used to copy multiple files. Would you post any simple example of multprocessing when used in conjunction with subprocess? I am posting a simple code below that could be modiefed to make it multy-processing/multy-threated. A simple example would be more that sufficient!

Comment: `Popen` is "asynchronous". It is the way to call external processes in Python.

Comment: It is _one_ way to call asynchronous processes in Python. Given your reminder, I will remove the second part of my answer and modify the first. If you want to be able to communicate picklable Python objects to your subprocesses then the subprocess module just won't do it - it was designed to mimic the same sort of process interactions that the shell does. [Edited to add my understanding of the difference between subprocess and multiprocess]

Comment: That should have been "if you want to communicate __non__-picklable objects"